# Read datas that are in %02x format from text file in java

Tags: java, file-io, arrays, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I wrote data to text file and this datas are in "%02x" format. My text file like;

"00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07".

Now, I want to read file and getting datas to byte array. How can I do this ?

Comment: Will a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) not serve your purpose?

Comment: No, I will get datas and append to byte array. After that I will create image from byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line = "00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07";
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for (String token : tokens) {
        bytes.add( Byte.parseByte(token) );
    }

    Object[] byteArray = bytes.toArray();
```